# have a problem with error 1 during install

Tags: adduser

I tried to create a new user using the CLI command

```
adduser
```

I did not follow the prompt instructions.  The command exited with a error value of one.  What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Are you actually hitting the 'Enter' key (or equivalent, in your language), or the 'Esc' key?

Comment: I was thinking that too, that the `^[` was indicative of a non-`Enter` keystroke.

Comment: I can't view the image from my current location, but I assume it is a terminal screenshot. Please do not post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text and use the formatting tools to make it look nice.

Answer (score 1):

leave the Options blank and just hit the `Enter` key if you don't want to provide the information as it already says in your screen:

> Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default